# a:hover does not work, with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So for some reason, my hover CSS is not working. I am using bootstrap with some of their css. Is there something wrong with my code, or is it because bootstrap's code is overriding mine's?

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" role="tablist">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>        
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
ul>li>a {
    color: black;
    padding: 15px;
}

ul>li>a:hover {
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because the default Bootstrap styling is [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

These are the selectors that you need to override:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Therefore you could use:

[**Working Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nfLr55vf/)

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #B0B0B0;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing exactly whats going on, the issue you're having may be related to not specifying a class on your unordered list.

This may fix the problem:

```
ul.navbar-nav > li > a {
color:black;
padding: 15px;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
    color:red;
}
```